# postgresql client - installation on php:5-apache

Tags: postgresql, docker, php-5.6

I work on some old project (Laravel 4.2, php5.6, postgresql) and I wanna to set it up on docker - here is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:5-apache

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    nano \
    libpng-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \ 
    postgresql-dev \  
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    unzip &&\
    a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo &&\
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql &&\
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql &&\
    docker-php-ext-install zip &&\
    docker-php-ext-install gd &&\
    docker-php-ext-install pcntl &&\ 
    docker-php-ext-install mcrypt

# COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

I get following error:

> E: Unable to locate package postgresql-dev

When I change `postgresql-dev` to `postgresql` (and change image to `FROM php:5-apache-jessie` with different combinations: `RUN dpkg --configure -a && RUN apt-get -f install && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*` I get errors like:

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
>
> E: Unable to locate package postgresql*
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql*'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql*'
>
> You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
>
> You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
>
> configure: error: Cannot find libpq-fe.h. Please specify correct PostgreSQL installation path

Question: **How to install postgres php client drivers properly?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `dockerfile` change `postgresql-dev \` to

```
libpq-dev \
```

Comment: The do it tomorrow ;)